# Java: Calc x in sin(x)

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

My question is about angle functions in programming languge Java. if i want to get sin of any double, i just use

```java
double variable = Math.sin(x);
```

but what if **sin(x) =  0.324** (or any other random number) and i want to calculate x? How can i do it? Are there any native function to this in java or i have to implement my own algorithm to return this value ?

```java
getXForValue(0.324);

public double getXForValue(double val){
 // how to calculate ?
 return x;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are describing is known as the "arcsine" function. It's available in Java as [Math.asin()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29).

You may want to read the [wiki on trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [arcsin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29) function

```
x = Math.asin(variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate sine inverse in Java you can use

```
Math.asin(double a)
```

It returns the arc sine of a value; the returned angle is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2.. Check java docs for more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.asin(0.324);` to get the value of x.

Please read the [Math.asin()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin%28double%29) javadoc to be aware of what is returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the inverse function or arcsine. It has the same relationship with sine as dividing has with multiplication.

```
5 * x = 10;
10 / 5 = x;

Math.sine(x) = 1;
Math.asine(1) = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the these Methods, `Math.toDegrees` and `Math.asin`, in the next order:

```
double x = 1.0; // in this example 1.0 corresp to sin(90)
double dX = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(x));

System.out.println(dX);
```

Remember that the `asin()` function return a `double RADIANS` result.